# How to convert an async function which returns promise to sync function in node js

Tags: node.js, csv, npm, fast-csv

I am using fast-csv npm library, where I wanted to use writeToString formatter function
https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/blob/HEAD/docs/formatting.md#csv-write-to-string

Current I write like

```
 const csvString = await csv.writeToString([{'id':'10','id':'12' }], {headers: false});
res.write(csvString, 'binary')
```

I wanted sync version of this like

```
 const csvString = csv.writeToString([{'id':'10','id':'12' }], {headers: false});
res.write(csvString, 'binary')
```

Any way I could achieve this? I am fine in any other npm csv library can support this

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using csv-stringify library sync module

```
const stringify = require('csv-stringify/lib/sync');

res.write(stringify([{'id':'10','id':'12' }], { header: false})
```